# Get the innerText of the H1 within the parent

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

We have some abstract links on our website. We want to track clicks on them combined with the H1 title to be able to identify the block it is clicked in. I am using Google Tagmanager. There are more blocks with the same structure on the page, the function is triggered on a click event.

Two hard requirements:

- **Without using jQuery.**
- **Needs to support IE9**

It is basically a block with a title and a list of links in it, the last one is "read more..". I want to create a function that returns the text of the link and the H1 in one string.

I use the gtm.click trigger and set this value in the label. For most links, the {{Click Text}} is enough, but not for this specific one.

In the end I want the function to do return this:

"Read more.. | Title"

I have the "Read more..", but I can't get the title from the H1 element above it.

https://gomakethings.com/climbing-up-and-down-the-dom-tree-with-vanilla-javascript/

Search for .parent-column, find H1 in parent-column, get innerText and add it to the {{Clicked Text}}.

```
   <div class="column-2 portlet-column span3" id="sdfghjkl">
    <div class="portlet-dropzone portlet-column-content portlet-spacing portlet-column-content-only" id="layout-column_column-2">
        <div class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_56_ portlet-static portlet-static-end portlet-borderless portlet-journal-content " id="fdsadf"> <span id="dsasdf"></span>
            <div class="portlet-borderless-container">
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <div class="journal-content-article">
                        <style>
                            span.icon img { background-repeat: no-repeat; }
                        </style>
                        <div class="news_headline headline_news" style="font-family: Noa LT Std;"> <img src="dsasdfds" alt="content" class="icon icon_spacing">
                            <h1> <span class="headline g-font-content">H1 content</span> </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry-links"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_56_ portlet-static portlet-static-end portlet-borderless portlet-journal-content " id="content"> <span id="content"></span>
            <div class="portlet-borderless-container">
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <div class="journal-content-article">
                        <div class="news_headline">
                            <div class="relatedArticles" style="margin-top:10px;">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="vertical-align: top;"> <img style="margin-left:9px; margin-right: 8px; color:#005B82;max-width:none;" src="content"> </td>
                                            <td> <a href="content" target="_blank"> <span class="g-font-content content-magazine-color">LINK</span> </a> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news_headline">
                            <div class="relatedArticles" style="margin-top:10px;">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="vertical-align: top;"> <img style="margin-left:9px; margin-right: 8px; color:#005B82;max-width:none;" src="content"> </td>
                                            <td> <a href="content" target="_blank"> <span class="g-font-content content-magazine-color">LINK</span> </a> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news_headline">
                            <div class="relatedArticles" style="margin-top:10px;">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="vertical-align: top;"> <img style="margin-left:9px; margin-right: 8px; color:#005B82;max-width:none;" src="content" target="_blank"> <span class="g-font-content content-magazine-color">Read more..</span> </a> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="entry-links"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
function() {
   labelh1 = {{Click Text}};

   if ({{Click Text}} == "Read more.."){

var parentElement = getClosest(event.target, '.parent-column');
var headingInParent = parentElement.querySelector('h1');
var labelh1 = {{Click Text}} + " | " + headingInParent.textContent

var getClosest = function ( elem, selector ) {
    if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
        Element.prototype.matches =
            Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector ||
            Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
            function(s) {
                var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
                    i = matches.length;
                while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
                return i > -1;
            };
    }
    // Get closest match
    for ( ; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode ) {
        if ( elem.matches( selector ) ) return elem;
    }
    return null;
};
 return labelh1;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe add the Javascript you already tested, so that we can have a working snippet.

Comment: Why not try using [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: Do you want  to  trigger this function when `Read more...` *link* is  clicked?

Comment: Yes when the read more is clicked

Comment: closest is jQuery @Pete

I see now in your link it is supported by Mozilla. I will look into it, it seems like the best solution

Comment: read the link @Bastiaan  that isn't jquery and there is a polyfill for ie

Answer (score 0):

Run the below snipped and click on "Read more..."

```js
var readMoreAnchors = contains('span', /^Read\smore/i);

    for(var i = 0; i < readMoreAnchors.length; ++i) {
        var readMoreAnchor = readMoreAnchors[i];

        addEvent('click', readMoreAnchor, function(event) {
            var parentElement = getClosest(event.target, '.portlet-dropzone');
            var headingInParent = parentElement.querySelector('h1');

            console.log("{{Click Text}}" + " | " + headingInParent.textContent);
        });
    }





    /**
     * Get the closest matching element up the DOM tree.
     * @private
     * @param  {Element} elem     Starting element
     * @param  {String}  selector Selector to match against
     * @return {Boolean|Element}  Returns null if not match found
     */
    var getClosest = function ( elem, selector ) {

        // Element.matches() polyfill
        if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
            Element.prototype.matches =
                Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
                Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
                Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
                Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector ||
                Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
                function(s) {
                    var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
                        i = matches.length;
                    while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
                    return i > -1;
                };
        }

        // Get closest match
        for ( ; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode ) {
            if ( elem.matches( selector ) ) return elem;
        }

        return null;

    };

    function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
        if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
            elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
        else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
            elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
        }
        else { // No much to do
            elem[evnt] = func;
        }
    }

    function contains(selector, text) {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element){
            return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
        });
    }
```

```html
<div class="column-2 portlet-column span3" id="sdfghjkl">
    <div class="portlet-dropzone portlet-column-content portlet-spacing portlet-column-content-only" id="layout-column_column-2">
        <div class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_56_ portlet-static portlet-static-end portlet-borderless portlet-journal-content " id="fdsadf"> <span id="dsasdf"></span>
            <div class="portlet-borderless-container">
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <div class="journal-content-article">
                        <style>
                            span.icon img { background-repeat: no-repeat; }
                        </style>
                        <div class="news_headline headline_news" style="font-family: Noa LT Std;"> <img src="dsasdfds" alt="content" class="icon icon_spacing">
                            <h1> <span class="headline g-font-content">H1 content</span> </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry-links"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_56_ portlet-static portlet-static-end portlet-borderless portlet-journal-content " id="content"> <span id="span-content"></span>
            <div class="portlet-borderless-container">
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    <div class="journal-content-article">
                        <div class="news_headline">
                            <div class="relatedArticles" style="margin-top:10px;">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: top;"> <img style="margin-left:9px; margin-right: 8px; color:#005B82;max-width:none;" src="https://marketplace.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/508/508664-64.png?modified=cdda3e8d"> </td>
                                        <td> <a href="content" target="_blank"> <span class="g-font-content content-magazine-color">LINK</span> </a> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news_headline">
                            <div class="relatedArticles" style="margin-top:10px;">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: top;"> <img style="margin-left:9px; margin-right: 8px; color:#005B82;max-width:none;" src="https://marketplace.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/508/508664-64.png?modified=cdda3e8d"> </td>
                                        <td> <a href="content" target="_blank"> <span class="g-font-content content-magazine-color">LINK</span> </a> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="news_headline">
                            <div class="relatedArticles" style="margin-top:10px;">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: top;"> <img style="margin-left:9px; margin-right: 8px; color:#005B82;max-width:none;" src="https://marketplace.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/508/508664-64.png?modified=cdda3e8d" target="_blank"> <a><span class="g-font-content content-magazine-color">Read more..</span> </a> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="entry-links"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Abdul, thanks for your help!

I think I was not entirely clear, I am using Google tagmanager, the intention is to create a Variable with this function. The variabel is already connected to a click event on the read more button.

Comment: Tried to make it work with these:
var parentElement = getClosest(event.target, '.parent-column');
            var headingInParent = parentElement.querySelector('h1');

            console.log(event.target.textContent + " | " + headingInParent.textContent);

In combination with the getClosest function, but I can't get it to work

Comment: "The variabel is already connected to a click event on the read more button." I couldn't understand what do you mean?

Comment: My intention is to create a custom variable in Google Tagmanager that reurns this value. https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106899?hl=en

Comment: In this url, do you want to create a **Custom JavaScript** web variable? As referred by `function () { return {{url}}.toLowerCase(); }` code.

Comment: Yes! Custom Javascript Variable. So I need something like this:

function() {
  
   var parentElement = getClosest(event.target, '.parent-column');
   var headingInParent = parentElement.querySelector('h1');
 var labelh1 = {{Click Text}} + " | " + headingInParent.textContent
    <code for getClosestfunction>
  return labelh1;
  

}

Comment: But this has to be attached as event handler to the link, so can't be called independently. Because `event` variable will only be available when it's called as event handler against a click. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I think, in your case, that you want to set a variable for Google Tag Manager against a DOM event, you can utilize **Data Layer**. ?

Comment: I have set up a Custom Event gtm.click that triggers on the click on the links. 

It fires a event (Track Type) with a cat, action & label. In the Label I have set up the {{Click Text}}. All of this works. Now I want to have the H1 attached to the {{Click Text}}, as there are multiple "Read more.." buttons on the page.

Comment: The `event` it fires, can you confirm that it has a property `target` which is a reference to clicked `a` tag?

So that we are sure that `getClosest(event.target, '.parent-column')` is applicable in this case.

Comment: <td> <a href="/url" target="_blank"> <span class="g-font-fancy nice-color">Read more..</span> </a> </td>

So it might be that it triggers on the <span> element, that causes the problem? it triggers on the Click Element = [object HTMLSpanElement]

Comment: The markup in your question, `a` is inside `span`. Is it changed now?

Comment: Edited the code to orginal, I really thought it would not matter for this example. (Thanks for your effort, really appriciated)

Comment: I've edited my answer. See if it works. Run the snipped and click *Read more...*. Note that I've changed `a` to `span` and parent to `.portlet-dropzone` (first immediate common parent of *link* and *h1*).

Comment: Still working on it, can log the value now, but there seems to be a scope issue in my case. I will let you know when I have it working.

Comment: It was a timing issue, function was executed without the DOM being present!

Comment: Hmmm. Have you fixed it?

Comment: I have a working solution, but prefer a better one. I will try now to let the eventlistener part fire on domready and getting the value in the Click.

Comment: Ok, great. Do let me know if you needed help.